# Existing algorithms to find shortest path on a non-weighted graph?

Tags: algorithm, vertices

I am tasked with writing a program that is capable of finding the shortest amount of moves from one vertex to another. The only data I have for the 'graph' is what vertex links to what vertex, no weights, distances etc.

I must parse an input to find these links initially. This input can have up to 1,000,000 vertices. I have already completed this.

I've looked at algorithms similar to and including Dijkstra's Algorithm, Floyd's Algorithm and even attempted Q Learning. Both Dijkstra and Floyd's Algorithms rely on distances between vertices, and Q Learning does not seem the most practical approach when dealing with hundreds of thousands of potential states and actions. Not only this, but the program must figure out the path within 2 seconds of being provided the input, ruling any kind of reinforcement learning completely useless - unless the algorithm can train hundreds of thousands of pieces of data within two seconds.

Are there any existing algorithms I can use to accomplish this goal? Is the some kind of general guideline I should follow if I must write my own?

Comment: Unless you have a way of proving that a path is the shortest without looking at the other paths, BFS is the way to go. If you can estimate how far nodes should be, and you are satisfied with a slightly less optimal path, A* would work too

Comment: Agree with @njzk2. And note that A* is optimal when using an admissable and consistent heuristic.

Comment: If all edges are considered equal, then you can just any shortest path algorithm using equal edge weights for every edge, a typical choice for weight would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph you're given has absolutely no indication of how far each vertex is from the end, I would suggest something similar to `Dijkstra's`.  The algorithm would look something like this:

```
The Node object should contain:
    LINKEDNODES = Array of linked nodes
    TRAVELLED = Integer for minimum number of nodes traversed from starting node, initialized as -1
NODES = A given array of nodes
START = the starting node
GOAL = the goal node
QUEUE = Create a priority queue that holds nodes and prioritizes based on their associated TRAVELLED
Give START a TRAVELLED value of 0

MAIN LOOP:
Check front of QUEUE, for each linked node:
   If the node is GOAL then set its TRAVELLED to current node + 1, and go to the next phase RETRACE
   Else If the node's TRAVELLED is -1
   Then set it's TRAVELLED value to current node + 1, and add it to QUEUE
   Otherwise, ignore it, since we don't want to check the same nodes twice

RETRACE:
   CNODE = Current node being checked
   PATH = an array of nodes, of size GOAL.TRAVELLED
   Set CNODE to GOAL
   Repeat until CNODE.TRAVELLED is 0 (which is START's TRAVELLED):
      Add CNODE to PATH
      Set CNODE to the LINKEDNODE of CNODE that has a TRAVELLED of CNODE.TRAVELLED - 1
```

As for the second problem, I hope you have a fast PC!

Comment: quick note: This is a BFS and your queue doesn't need to do the prioritization, since poping from the head and pushing at the tail guarantees that the stack is in order of traveled value